# SQL joins show same record 3 times, instead of 3 records

Tags: sql

I am working on a join exercise from Database Processing by Kroenke and Auer
There is a question which asks to find all the items shipped from Singapore displaying information from 3 different tables.

In the table there is 3 results which match these criteria.

I have tried a where join and an inner join, but each time instead of giving 3 results, it gives 1 result 3 times, which makes me convinced I'm messing something up with my syntax.

Here's the where join:

```
    select  shippername, shipment.shipmentId, departuredate 
     FROM shipment, item, SHIPMENT_ITEM
     WHERE shipment_item.shipmentID = shipment.shipmentID
     AND item.itemId = shipment_Item.itemID 
     AND item.city = 'Singapore';
```

And the inner join:

```
 select   shippername, shipment.shipmentId, departuredate 
FROM shipment 
INNER JOIN shipment_item ON shipment_item.shipmentID = shipment.shipmentID
INNER JOIN item ON item.itemId = shipment_Item.itemID 
WHERE item.city = 'Singapore'
order by shippername asc,
 departuredate desc;
```

The result of both queries:

```
shippername                         shipmentId  departuredate
----------------------------------- ----------- -------------
International                       4           2013-06-02
International                       4           2013-06-02
International                       4           2013-06-02
```

Comment: The rows are probably different.  Try including `item.*` in the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a Distinct after the select, but probably there's something different in each row, try select all columns as Gordon suggested to see what's different between them

Answer (score 0):

Looks like more Items in One shipment,
So if you want Shipment based detail try `GROUP_CONCAT` with `group by`.

```
SELECT shippername,
          shipment.shipmentId,
          departuredate ,
          GROUP_CONCAT(item.itemId) AS items_shiped
    FROM    shipment 
    INNER JOIN shipment_item ON shipment_item.shipmentID = shipment.shipmentID
    INNER JOIN item ON item.itemId = shipment_Item.itemID 
    WHERE item.city = 'Singapore'
    GROUP BY shipment.shipmentId
    order by shippername asc,
     departuredate desc;
```

Hope this helps.